# Why do I keep hearing that Americans are running down their pandemic savings but the data doesn't show that?

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, saving, credit, consumer-credit

I keep hearing on the news etc. that Americans are running down their savings, even from well known figures like the head of Blackrock etc. Granted I have not been looking at economists specifically. They say it almost as if it is clear as day.

I looked on FRED and I saw:

- **credit card debt has increased by a significant amount** (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CCLACBW027SBOG)
- **personal savings is low relatively speaking** (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/PSAVE)

However I also saw:

- **household checkable depoists are way up and remain elevated** (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/BOGZ1FL193020005Q)

Seems like the average consumer is still flush with cash and not really struggling much at all besides getting their current paychecks eaten up faster. Am I missing something?